# Shopping Cart Total Price and Quantity

Tags: javascript

Below there's a shopping cart that when you remove the product it works and price gets updated, but when I try to add more quantity like 2 or 3 then Total Price doesn't get updated, but when I remove the product it gets updated and that's where's the problem that I don't know how to solve it.
Also I have added an function with quantity so the minimum of order could be only 1 and if you try to add less than 1 like 0 or -1,-2 it will be changed automatically at number 1, but doesn't work and I need some help.

### p.s: This is only an exercise so there's no PHP or something else.

````
<div class="click-cart">
        <div class="cart-row">
            <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
            <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
            <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span></div>
          <div class="olp">
            <div class="lakn">
            <img class="shop-item-cart" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
            <span class="shop-title">Product 1</span>
            <span class="shop-price">$19.99</span>
            <input class="quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="delete-cart">X</button>
          </div></div>
            <div class="clear-checkout">
          <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>
          <button class="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button></div>
          <div class="cart-total">
              <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
              <span class="cart-total-price">$10.79</span>
          </div>
      </div>```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
let removeCartItemButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-cart'); 
    for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    let button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem) 
    }

    let quantityInputs = document.querySelector('.quantity-input');
    for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        let input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    }

function removeCartItem (event) {
        let buttonCliked = event.target;
        buttonCliked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
        updateCartTotal()
    }

    function quantityChanged () {
        let input = event.target
        if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal ()
}

function updateCartTotal () {
    let cartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.click-cart');
    let cartRows = cartItemContainer.querySelector('.cart-row');
    let total = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        let cartRow = cartRows[i]
        let priceElement = cartRow.querySelector('.shop-price');
        let quantityElement = cartRow.querySelectorAll('.quantity-input');
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        let quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.querySelector('.cart-total-price').innerText = '$' + total;
}
````

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" >
        <div>
            <div class="click-cart">
                <div class="cart-row2">
                    <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                    <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                    <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div class="lakn">
                        <img class="shop-item-cart" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
                        <span class="shop-title">Product 1</span>
                        <span class="shop-price">$19.99</span>
                        <input class="quantity-input" type="number" value="1" />
                        <button class="delete-cart">X</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear-checkout">
                    <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>
                    <button class="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-total">
                    <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                    <span class="cart-total-price">$10.79</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        let removeCartItemButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-cart');
        for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {

            let button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
            button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
        }

        let quantityInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-input');
        for (let i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {

            let input = quantityInputs[i]
            input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
        }

        function removeCartItem(event) {
            let buttonCliked = event.target;
            buttonCliked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            updateCartTotal()
        }

        function quantityChanged() {

            let input = event.target;
            if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
                input.value = 1;
            }
            updateCartTotal()
        }

        function updateCartTotal() {
            let cartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.click-cart');
            let cartRows = cartItemContainer.querySelectorAll('.cart-row');

            let total = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
                let cartRow = cartRows[i]
                let priceElement = cartRow.querySelector('.shop-price');
                let quantityElement = cartRow.querySelector('.quantity-input');

                let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
                let quantity = quantityElement.value
                total = total + (price * quantity)
            }
            total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
            document.querySelector('.cart-total-price').innerText = '$' + total;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah now price is getting updated but when I add 2 quantity and the price of product is $19.99 with another quantity it should be total $39.98 but instead the price changes to $0 when you change quantity 1 to 2 or more and if I remove the product Total price doesn't changes still ?
But good thing is that now quantity updates automatically, only the price doesn't for now !

Comment: in my browser work fine without any problem .
may be you should clear browser cache
click ctrl+f5

Comment: it works now because I didn't added "           <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>". Can you explain me why you added id"form1" and runat="server" ?

Comment: @RazmikGhookas, please don't answer by providing nothing other than a "code dump" (particularly if large chunks of it are identical to code in the question). You should explain *why* and *how* the code you propose resolves the OPs problem, rather than assuming that they, or anyone else who looks at it later, will be able to determine this clearly themselves

Comment: @Behar
i edited my answer 
remove runat="server" because the code run in client side
also change class name of div elemen to "cart-row" please compare my code with yours

Comment: @RazmikGhookas yep I changed class of div to cart-row but there's another problem on my Codepen link below. 
I'm trying to make possible to add product to cart when I click button "Add to Cart" from the product, but it's not working and it's showing me some errors saying "cartItemContainer is not a function" and some other errors and i tried to fix but didn't had any success, any chance you can take a look and see what's wrong if you have time?
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/ywdJMM

Comment: @RazmikGhookas Here's some screenshots from my error showing on Console Log

https://prnt.sc/n3q2yo
https://prnt.sc/n3q45j

Comment: @Behar hello let me check it

Comment: @Behar
 
it is syntax error you wrote  getElementByClassName
and must be 
getElementsByClassName

Comment: Yeah that error solved my issue and now Console Log it works, but there's a problem with my quantity when I increase it by 2 or 3 it doesn't update the price and if I remove product "Total" doesn't changes?
I made some changes after you helped me first and I have the same code now as you did 2 days ago when you fixed for me to update quantity etc, but it doesn't work now and I have no idea where's problem and even Console Log doesn't show any errors ?
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/ywdJMM

Comment: It works when I use the same code you made 2 days ago when you helped me with errors where it was and it works for quantity and price is updating now too so it's ok with your code, but in your code I changed querySelector to getElementsByClassName and that's all I changed but still with getElementsByClassName it doesn't work ?
Would you mind taking a look and see why my code doesn't update the price with 
getElementsByClassName ?
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/WmqpPK

Comment: @Behar
ok no problem let me check it

Comment: @Behar
i fixed your code 
now you can add product to cart 
change quantity 
update total price
delete item from cart ... 
[link](https://codepen.io/ghokas/pen/RdzgBX)
check above link 
i was changed html & css & js files 
please compare them with your sources .

Comment: Thanks a lot man finally it works :)
Btw can you tell me why you removed "<form id="form1" runat="server">", will it work without runat="server" ?

Comment: @Behar
in your case all process are happen in client side and no interactive by server.
you can add the form tag it will work .

Comment: oh ok thank you again for all the help mate, thanks a lot :)